# convert mysql timestamp into actual date and time?

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have dates stored in a mysql table, they are set to store as CURRENT TIMESTAMP in each row and are stored as follows:

```
2010-05-29 01:17:35
```

but what i am trying to do is somehow use PHP to be able to seperate everything and create a date more like:

**May 29 2010 1:17 AM**

can anyone at least direct me in the right path that i should take. any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
echo date('M j Y g:i A', strtotime('2010-05-29 01:17:35'));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Be sure to check out *Localized Notations* in the PHP manual on the Compound Formats page http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php

Answer (score 27):

You have two solutions :

- Use [**`strtotime()`**](https://www.php.net/strtotime) to parse the date to a timestamp, and [**`date()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to re-format it to a string
- Or use the [**`DateTime`**](https://www.php.net/datetime) class

In PHP code, this would mean using :

```
echo date('M j Y g:i A', strtotime('2010-05-29 01:17:35'));
```

Or :

```
$dt = new DateTime('2010-05-29 01:17:35');
echo $dt->format('M j Y g:i A');
```

`strtotime` + `date` is the solution you'll see used the most ; but it is not the best solution : with those, you'll work on UNIX Timestamps, which means a limited range of dates *(from 1970 to 2038, if using 32 bits integers)*.

ON the other hand, using the `DateTime` class, there will be no limit to the range of dates you can work with.

Comment: ["The range is from about 292 billion years in the past to the same in the future."](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php) - Wouldn't really call that *"no limit"*. Oh well, +1 anyway. ;-)))

Comment: Humph, I was sure there was someone going to say that this is not *unlimited* ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `DATETIME` field in your table and you only want the date field, then:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%M %D, %Y') FROM Mytable;
```

or:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') FROM Mytable;
```

where `timestamp` is your column name.