# How to convert MySQL TIMESTAMP to date time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp, formatdatetime

I have a MySQL DB table with a column named `"timestamp"`, a type of `timestamp`, and attribute of `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and a default of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

If I add a record to the table, specifying other values, but not the timestamp, then the timestamp is automatically added like `2016-12-28 17:02:26`.

In PHP I query the table using the following query

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE user_id = 9 ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

The result of the query is saved into `$rows` and I use a `foreach` to create an array with some of the other values formatted. I am attempting to format the time stamp to UK type 24-hour date time: `dd/mm/yy, HH:MM:SS`.

I have tried both the `date()` and `strftime()` functions as follows:

```
$formatted_datetime = strftime("%d %m %y  %H %M %S", $row["timestamp"]); 
$formatted_datetime = date("d/m/y, H:i:s", $row["timestamp"]);
```

Both of these result in the following notice and the date time being output incorrectly like `01 01 70 00 33 36`:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset7/public/history.php on line 20

I am new to PHP and MySQL and so far none of the other questions or documentation I have seen have successfully addressed performing this conversion.I do not understand why `strftime()` does not work, nor how to do this properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert mysql timestamp into actual date and time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547252/convert-mysql-timestamp-into-actual-date-and-time)

Comment: Sidenote: I wouldn't use `TIMESTAMP` due to its limitations: *"The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to **'2038-01-19 03:14:07'** UTC."* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html use `DATETIME` *"The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to **'9999-12-31 23:59:59'.**"*

Comment: @Tiger The selected solution there seems... like a lot. Would I benefit from a different type for the timestamp column on my table?

Comment: That 2038 is a UNIX bug http://stackoverflow.com/q/2012589/1415724 - Edit: You deleted the comment I was responding to.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, I noticed your "Sidenote:" bit at the start and realised my comment was unnecessary. Thanks though!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, I admit I edited my first comment a few times. But now you know about that UNIX bug; the choice is yours to keep going with that. Just thought I'd let you know about it so you don't get any unpleasant surprises later on.

Comment: @Fred-ii- In addition to changing to DATETIME I added a trigger to set the default value (my MySQL instance must not be the most recent as it does not allow `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a DATETIME default): `CREATE TRIGGER <triggername> BEFORE INSERT ON  <tablename> 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.<datetimefield> = NOW()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this the OO (and most flexible) way use `DateTime` class and use the static `createFromFormat` method to instantiate a new `DateTime` object:

```
$new_datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat ( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $row["timestamp"] );
```

Now you can use the `$new_datetime` object to generate any string representation you'd like by calling the object's `format` method:

```
echo $new_datetime->format('d/m/y, H:i:s');
```

To boot, you since you've a `DateTime` object you can now also to any manner of transformation (like shifting timezones or adding days), comparison (greater or less than another `DateTime`), and various time calculations (how many days/months/etc... between this and another `DateTime`).

DateTime:http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
Learn it. Love it. Live it.

Comment: This doesn't work if you need milliseconds.  Try one of the other ways listed.  :wink:

Answer (score 5):

Normally in MySQL date timestamp save time as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (2016-12-20 18:36:14)` formate you can easily convert them as your wish using date formate but have to convert your input to time first. Following will do the trick

```
$formatted_datetime = date("d/m/y, H:i:s", strtotime($row["timestamp"]));
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, while it may not be the OO way, strtotime will work just fine for MySQL timestamps.

Comment: @DevonBessemer not if they have milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Why not make MySQL do the work?  And do you really want mm/dd/yy, not dd/mm/yy?

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%m/%d/%y, %T') formatted_date FROM ....
```

Then you can extract the formatted date as $row['formatted_date'].

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Whoops, you are correct, I do want dd/mm/yy, thanks. I'll edit fothwith!

Comment: I had seens DATE_FORMAT() mentioned but only in relation to `SELECT DATE_FORMAT...` and wasn't sure how to adapt it, I'll give it a try

Comment: This works and I like the neatness of it, but I think Ray's DateTime object method is a bit more flexible.

Comment: This will work to generate the desired output, but moves application logic into MySQL, which is general a bad architectual choice.  Reasons not to do this are such as  code portability -- changing DB's (to say oracle or postges) may change the functions available, your SQL would then be invalid.

Comment: Using a DateTime object definitely gets you a more capable object and it is probably more portable (SQL server, for instance, does not appear to have a DATE_FORMAT function, although PostgreSQL does).  It's just slower.  Which you may well not care about in the circumstances.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The date is of `timestamp` type which has the following format: ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS’ or ‘2008-10-05 21:34:02.’

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM times;");
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ) {
   echo $row['date'] . "
";
}
```

The PHP strtotime function parses the MySQL timestamp into a Unix timestamp which can be utilized for further parsing or formatting in the PHP date function.

Here are some other sample date output formats that may be of practical use:

```
echo date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime($row["date"]));                  // October 5, 2008 9:34 pm
echo date("m.d.y", strtotime($row["date"]));                         // 10.05.08
echo date("j, n, Y", strtotime($row["date"]));                       // 5, 10, 2008
echo date("Ymd", strtotime($row["date"]));                           // 20081005
echo date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.', strtotime($row["date"]));   // It is the 5th day.
echo date("D M j G:i:s T Y", strtotime($row["date"]));               // Sun Oct 5 21:34:02 PST 2008
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Carbon class](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and its String Formatting

```
$carbon = Carbon::instance('2016-12-28 17:02:26');
```

Then you can format it the way you want.

Comment: Important to note, Carbon is a third party extension to the PHP DateTime API.

Comment: @Devon True but very useful. It is so good that it comes  with Laravel

Comment: Yes, I use it almost every day.  Not sure why this was downvoted, Carbon is a great solution for those who wish to use the library.  +1 to restore the balance.

Comment: @Devon yes me too, saves me much pain. Thank's for my balance ;)